# CUPS Processing - "Waiting for printer to become available."

Tags: printing, cups

I'm attempting to get  [Brother HL-L2301-D](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=hll2310d_us_eu_as) printer running under Gentoo.

I've downloaded the RPM and installed it under Gentoo.  The device is detected and I've set up a udev rule to make it available at `/dev/usb/lp0`, although it now appears there not as a symbolic link as it did yesterday but is still present at that location

```
# lsusb | grep -i brother
Bus 001 Device 100: ID 04f9:009a Brother Industries, Ltd HL-L2310D series
# l /dev/usb/lp0 
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 0 Apr 21 10:24 /dev/usb/lp0
```

I've tried adding the printer in two ways after reading [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2204606) that suggested using the `usb://Brother/HL-L2310D%20series?serial=###` rather than `usb://dev/usb/lp0`...

```
# lpadmin -p Chompy -E -v usb://Brother/HL-L2310D%20series?serial=E78096L9N400161 -i /usr/share/ppd/cupsfilters/brother-HLL2310D-cups-en.ppd -L "Study"
# lpadmin -p Chompy2 -E -v usb://dev/usb/lp0 -P /usr/share/ppd/brother/brother-HLL2310D-cups-en.ppd
```

The printer is turned on and lights indicate its "Ready", both `Chompy` and `Chompy2` (daughter chose the name, quite perceptive for 6yo!) are listed in the CUPS WebUI and yet if I try to print a test page to either I'm told...

```
Processing - "Waiting for printer to become available."
```

Checking with `lstat`

```
# lpstat -o "Chompy" -p -l
Chompy-22               root              1024   Tue 21 Apr 2020 10:25:17 BST
printer Chompy now printing Chompy-22.  enabled since Tue 21 Apr 2020 10:25:17 BST
    Waiting for printer to become available.
```

Same happens if I try using `Chompy2`.

Stumped as to what to try next, any suggestions would be gratefully received.  I'm keen to get this working and then share it on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen today with a Canon MP480. I fixed it by deleting and re-adding the printer through the CUPs web GUI (i.e., http://localhost:631). It showed an option for a locally connected USB printer, which I chose.

[screenshot of Add Printer screen showing local printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E29i.png)

Not sure why this made it start working, but I suspect it may happen when you plug the printer into a different USB port on the computer than when the printer was first installed in CUPS. Today, the web GUI gave me a connection string with an extra `interface` parameter:

```
usb://Canon/MP480%20series?serial=<serial_num>&interface=1
```

which may reflect the `bInterfaceNumber` value from `lsusb -v` (excerpt below):

```
  bNumConfigurations      1
    bConfigurationValue     1
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval              11
      bInterfaceNumber        1
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case, this helped:

`ls /dev/usb/lp0` gives `/dev/usb/lp0`

In Ubuntu 16.04:
System > Printer > Choose your Printer > Properties

Change address from `/dev/us/lp0` to `usb`, then click Apply.

Comment: This answer isn't complete, in that I have no idea what you're suggesting. Please add more so the answer can stand alone.